# Jsp passing parameter to subdatset in jrxml

Tags: java, jsp, jasper-reports

I want to pass a parameter from `jsp` to `jrxml` that is used inside a query in subdataset, but when I try I always get empty pdf.

If I try the sql without parameter I have no problem. So I'm guessing that something is wrong in how I pass the parameter.

**show.jsp**

```
<%
    Connection conn = null;
    //int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("ID"));
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test","root","passwd1234");

        File reportFile = new File(application.getRealPath("//T0113.jasper"));
        System.out.println(reportFile);
        Map parameters = new HashMap();
        String sqlCondition = "A11";
        parameters.put("id",sqlCondition);
        byte[] bytes = JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(reportFile.getPath(),parameters,conn);
        System.out.println(parameters);
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.setContentLength(bytes.length);
        ServletOutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
        outStream.write(bytes,0,bytes.length);
        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();  
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        out.println("Error : " + ex.getMessage());
    }


%>
```

**my jrxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.2.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.2.0  -->
<!-- 2016-01-14T16:09:41 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="T0113" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="84489b82-cfa1-489a-a5e2-404ca58708d2">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="TEST0114"/>
    <style name="Table_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <subDataset name="T0113" uuid="e911ce63-0ce5-4bb2-b3c8-e6b41cba5852">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="TEST0114"/>
        <parameter name="id" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[select * from person where '$P{id}']]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="ID" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="NAME" class="java.lang.Integer">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <group name="ID">
            <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{ID}]]></groupExpression>
        </group>
        <group name="NAME">
            <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{NAME}]]></groupExpression>
        </group>
    </subDataset>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[select * from person]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="ID" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="NAME" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <group name="ID">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{ID}]]></groupExpression>
    </group>
    <group name="NAME">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{NAME}]]></groupExpression>
    </group>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="215" splitType="Stretch">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="170" y="15" width="200" height="200" uuid="02e57f61-e30e-429f-a8c6-487a18e7ed07">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.VerticalRowLayout"/>
                </reportElement>
                <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="T0113" uuid="dd2d7275-311a-4bd0-b7d8-d9948ddc3c1c">
                        <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:column width="100" uuid="a3a9e148-5c8d-44c9-a76d-38a1b86daf01">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="8eba1ee4-42c7-4908-a97b-88b6a53faa1e"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[ID]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="5ee52917-3b1b-4ba3-aed8-581662fb8cd9"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ID}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="100" uuid="7a689d13-3e08-4683-a53b-768c15825885">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="d821fdb7-948a-4f67-90d8-3bf9f0f6da70"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[NAME]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="0f29f475-aff1-4bad-855a-145e393717cd"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{NAME}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                </jr:table>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="125" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </detail>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

**error message**

```
parameter index out of range (1 number of parameters which is 0)
```

Comment: What is you question?, how can I debug my query in jasper report? (this I could answer), How to pass parameter? (this is a duplicate of another question). Whats wrong here? (this need [mcve])

Comment: @PetterFriberg my question is how to pass value from jsp to *.jasper

Comment: @PetterFriberg the value cna't pass to

Comment: @PetterFriberg Thank you very much.

Comment: Note to close review, the question has been edit by user to include a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the parameter **correctly** from `jsp` to `jrxml`, this is not your problem.

**The problem is** that you are not passing the parameter from main report to your `subDataset`, actually the parameter does not exists in main report.

**Solution:**

1. Define the parameter also in the **main report**, with same name.

   ```
   <parameter name="id" class="java.lang.String"/>
   ```

   This definition will be under your `subDataset`
2. Pass the main report parameter in your `datasetRun` expression to your `subDataset`

   ```
   <datasetRun subDataset="T0113" uuid="dd2d7275-311a-4bd0-b7d8-d9948ddc3c1c">
       <datasetParameter name="id">
           <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{id}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
       </datasetParameter>
       <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
   </datasetRun>
   ```

To understand this you need to think of `subDataset` as a subreport, as another report. The parameter in you main report are not automatically present in the `subDataset` they need to be defined and their values need to be passed.

If you wan't to pass **all** parameter in once you can also pass the whole parameter map to your `subdataset` using this expression. (note, you still need to define them in both main report and `subdataset`)

```
<datasetRun subDataset="T0113" uuid="dd2d7275-311a-4bd0-b7d8-d9948ddc3c1c">
        <parametersMapExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.HashMap($P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP})]]></parametersMapExpression>
        <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
</datasetRun>
```

Some comments outside of the questions scope

1. Its seems that you have a typo on this query `select * from person
   where '$P{id}'`, it probably should be something like `select * from
   person where theCorrectColumnNameThatIsAVarChar =  $P{id}`
2. I see that detail band is empty, there is no need to execute the
   query `select * from person` in main report, if you like to display
   report with empty datasource  just use the attribute
   `whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail"` on the `jasperReport` tag

Comment: sorry,I try this way but I can't compile can you show me *.jrxml?

Comment: @Pei What is your compilation error?, I have also edit the the answer to show you that probably you have a typo in query...

Comment: when I want Jrxml compile to Jasper I'll get the error "No repository found at http://jasperstudio.sf.net/jssproductrepo_E4_CE/."

Comment: If I didn't add <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{id}]]></datasetParameterExpression> in datasetRun, I can compile sucess

Comment: I using JasperStudio and <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{id}]]></datasetParameterExpression> still have error I post my code

Comment: I guess you forgot to do point 1?, where is the parameter definition in the main report?, it should be before the query in main report...

Comment: theCorrectColumnNameThatIsAVarChar naturaly needs to be a column of yours, I don't know which though since I can't see the database...

Comment: maybe I find problem, when I delet $P{id} in datasetParameterExpression I will compile finish. like it "<datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[]]></datasetParameterExpression>"

Comment: Hmm, the edit you have done does not complete point 1, you need to add the parameter also in mainreport not just in subdataset, then you can pass it to subdataset...

Comment: and I edit my theCorrectColumnNameThatIsAVarChar finish. It's ="ID"

Comment: ok I keep to try,If I have problem plz still teach me, thank you very mush

Comment: You are missing this parameter in main report: '</subDataset>
 <parameter name="id" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"/>
 <queryString>',  i have included the closing tag '</subDataset>' and start tag '<queryString>' so you under stand where...